# Need to write regular expression in javascript which matches a particular pattern(digit/decimal - digit/decimal) in entire string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write logic in javascript for a string from backend which should contain one specific pattern.

Patter should be:- digit/decimal hyphen digit/decimal(eg:- "100 - 300", "1 - 9.999", "2.8 - 300"like this)

I have tried below logic but it is checking only first character of the string and it's getting failed if any other string comes from backend(eg:- **100 Nuvera - (c900Link)bunch** ).
Please suggest if anyone have better way.

```
inputVisibility:function(w,g){
  var regex1 = /^[\d\-\d]/g;
  var strs = regex1.exec(w);
  return ( strs !== null && g === "S")?true:false;
}
```

Comment: Try it like this `\b\d+(?:\.\d+)? - \d+(?:\.\d+)?\b` https://regex101.com/r/Cfgaqv/1

Comment: @ranjan nair - You write _digit/decimal hyphen digit/decimal_. What about the spaces around the hyphen?

Comment: Does the regex have to match "100 Nuvera - (c900Link)bunch"?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response \b\d+(?:\.\d+)? - \d+(?:\.\d+)?\b this worked for me exaclty.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to capture the optional decimal part:

```
(\d*(\.\d+)?) - (\d*(\.\d+)?)
```

What happens here is

```
\d*      > Match any number of digits
(\.\d+)? > Optionally match a literal decimal point followed by 1..n digits
```

If you need to extract the single values the relevant matching groups would be 1 & 3.

https://regex101.com/r/7OoYUz/1

Comment: thank you for your response, this partially worked but again for 9.999.999 it failed

Answer (score 0):

The most easy part is to omit any groups.

```js
const check = string => /^\d+\.?\d* - \d+\.?\d*$/.test(string);

console.log(["100 - 300", "1 - 9.999", "2.8 - 300", "100 Nuvera - (c900Link)bunch"].map(check));
```

Comment: yes it was helpfull but when the string has 9.99.9.9 it bypassed couple of my logics.but thanks for your response